# Unable to connect SQLState=08004 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in ms odbc administrator

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, tnsnames, instantclient

I want to add two service names in one tnsnames.ora file and getting error
in below 2 image in "Microsoft ODBC Driver Configuration".
[image]

Comment: Well, which of the two TNS aliases are you referencing?  What is in your sqlnet.ora file?  Can you connect using that TNS alias via `SQL*Plus`?  Can you `tnsping` it?

Comment: both the alias names are referencing to 2 different database and yes i can ping.actually i am using oracle client and i don't have database in my pc i am connecting with ip address,servername and i don't know what is sqlnet.ora file

Comment: You can ping.  Can you `tnsping`?  Can you connect via `SQL*Plus`?  Which of the two aliases are you using in your ODBC connection?  How are you configuring your ODBC connection?  The `sqlnet.ora` file is in the same directory as the `tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: i don't know how to do tnsping and also don't know sql*plus.I am using ALXTEST and ALXORCL two aliases.I am using Microsoft ODBC Source Administrator for configuring which is in systemWow64 folde.There is no sqlnet.ora file is present in the directory i am using only instantclient_12_1

Answer (score 5):

One trick which help me is, when you fill:

```
Data Source Name     Test
TNS Service Name     10.1.1.105:1521/ALXTEST
```

so you need to specify the `hostname:port/servicename`, then it should work

Comment: This worked for me. I don't really need it in the TNS names file. I just need to be able to connect via DSN.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and on a specific version of Oracle (instant client 11.2), I added .World after the tnsname and it worked.

ALXTEST.World =
(description =
...
(service_name =ALXTEST.World

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

click on start icon->type **cmd** in the text box-> you can see cmd.exe-> click on it-> type **tnsping** click enter.

check whether you can connect to the destination or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes
This is the answer for Error in ODBC using TNS provided above:
[oracle odbc driver sqlstate 08004 ora 12154 tns]
It is working on Oracle 19 for 32 bit also on Windows 11:
See the image attached.

Original answer/message here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62892257/22208353
Data Source Name     Test123xyz
TNS Service Name     10.1.1.105:1521/ALXTEST

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXqR.png)